# Elasticsearch Failed to find analyzer but it creates index without any error

Tags: search, elasticsearch, n-gram

Here is my index settings json, when I test
http://localhost:9200/myIndex/_analyze?text="testing the analyzer"&analyzer=nGram_analyzer
 I am getting the following exception.

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "remote_transport_exception",
        "reason": "[Infectia][127.0.0.1:9300][indices:admin/analyze[s]]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "failed to find analyzer [nGram_analyzer]"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

index settings

```
  {
      "myIndex": {
        "mappings": {
          "practices": {
            "properties": {
              "practiceCity": {
                "type": "string",
                "index":"analyzed",
                "analyzer": "nGram_analyzer"
              },
              "practiceId": {
                "type": "long",
                "index":"not_analyzed"
              },
              "practiceName": {
                "type": "string",
                "boost": 10,
                "index":"analyzed",
                "analyzer": "nGram_analyzer"
              },
              "practicePhone": {
                "type": "long",
                "boost": 10,
                "index":"analyzed",
                "analyzer": "nGram_analyzer"
              },
              "practiceService": {
                "type": "string",
                "boost": 5,
                "index":"not_analyzed"
              }
            }
          },
          "users": {
            "_all": {
              "analyzer": "nGram_analyzer"
            },
            "properties": {
              "userCityId": {
                "type": "long",
                "index":"not_analyzed",
                "analyzer": "nGram_analyzer"
              },
              "userCityName": {
                "type": "string",
                "index":"not_analyzed"
              },
              "userEmail": {
                "type": "string",
                "index":"analyzed",
                "analyzer": "nGram_analyzer"
              },
              "userFirstName": {
                "type": "string",
                "boost": 10,
                "index":"analyzed",
                "analyzer": "nGram_analyzer"
              },
              "userId": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "userLastName": {
                "type": "string",
                "boost": 10,
                "index":"analyzed",
                "analyzer": "nGram_analyzer"
              },
              "userMobile": {
                "type": "string",
                "index":"analyzed",
                "analyzer": "nGram_analyzer"
              },
              "userSpecialization": {
                "type": "string",
                "boost": 5,
                "index":"not_analyzed"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "settings": {
          "index": {
            "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
             "nGram_analyzer": {
                "type":      "custom",
                "tokenizer": "standard",
                  "filter": [
                    "nGram_filter"
                  ]
                }
              },
              "filter": {
                "nGram_filter": {
                  "max_gram": "20",
                  "type": "edgeNGram",
                  "min_gram": "3",
                  "token_chars": [
                    "letter",
                    "digit",
                    "punctuation",
                    "symbol"
                  ]
                }
              }
            },
            "number_of_replicas": "1",
            "number_of_shards": "5"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

I am working on the auto complete functionality, is my index looks good?
is there any suggestions for performance improvement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `settings` section like this: (i.e. `analysis` goes directly under `settings` not in `index`)

```
PUT myindex
{
  "mappings": {
    "practices": {
      "properties": {
        "practiceCity": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "analyzed",
          "analyzer": "nGram_analyzer"
        },
        "practiceId": {
          "type": "long",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "practiceName": {
          "type": "string",
          "boost": 10,
          "index": "analyzed",
          "analyzer": "nGram_analyzer"
        },
        "practicePhone": {
          "type": "long",
          "boost": 10
        },
        "practiceService": {
          "type": "string",
          "boost": 5,
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    },
    "users": {
      "properties": {
        "userCityId": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "userCityName": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "userEmail": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "analyzed",
          "analyzer": "nGram_analyzer"
        },
        "userFirstName": {
          "type": "string",
          "boost": 10,
          "index": "analyzed",
          "analyzer": "nGram_analyzer"
        },
        "userId": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "userLastName": {
          "type": "string",
          "boost": 10,
          "index": "analyzed",
          "analyzer": "nGram_analyzer"
        },
        "userMobile": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "analyzed",
          "analyzer": "nGram_analyzer"
        },
        "userSpecialization": {
          "type": "string",
          "boost": 5,
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_replicas": "1",
      "number_of_shards": "5"
    },
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "nGram_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "nGram_filter"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "nGram_filter": {
          "max_gram": "20",
          "type": "edgeNGram",
          "min_gram": "3",
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit",
            "punctuation",
            "symbol"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry to say this... not working Val, same error response.
I have just copied your fixed index settings node.

Comment: I've fixed the problem and updated my answer, please try again.

Comment: No sir, it's not fixed yet, getting same error response.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the full thing. It works perfectly on my end. Note that I had to remove the analyzer setting on long fields otherwise ES complains.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, it is working now.
1. I want to search the documents from java in this scenario which Query type is perfect for partial keywords match with optimum performance on multiple fields to consider in matching process.

Comment: Since you have an ngram analyzer already you can start with `multi_match`. Feel free to create another question with a more specific description concerning your search issues.